# CA2122: Do not indirectly expose methods with link demands. How to fix it in my code

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop

CA2122: Do not indirectly expose methods with link demands.

My code is as follows:

```
public void LoadPage(Uri url)
{
    webBrowser1.Url = url;    //webBrowser1 is an object of WebBrowser
    webBrowser1.Refresh();
}
```

Fxcop produced the warning "CA2122: Do not indirectly expose methods with link demands."

1. Why this warning appeared on my code?
2. How to fix it?
3. How can I grant permission to my code to fullfill Code access security (CAS) attribute. i.e  I have an attribute on a method like this 
   [EnvironmentPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = false)]

What permission I have give my code and How for above mentioned attribute?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/a92a2d6f-de67-421a-83f7-7d7a34c629f9